# node_modules/_crypto-js@3.1.9-1@crypto-js/SHA256.web.js doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I installed crypto.js, but when I build my project copied from others to learn, it gave me an error:

> "node_modules/_crypto-js@3.1.9-1@crypto-js/SHA256.web.js doesn't exist"

I've try the commands including:

1. "npm install crypto-js" ,
2. "cnpm install crypto-js" ,
3. "sudo npm install crypto-js"
4. "sudo cnpm install crypto-js"

but nothing is fixed.

Comment: How did you require and use `crypto-js`?

Comment: const sha256 = require('crypto-js/SHA256')  

const hpw = sha256(pw).toString();

And I use hpw as body.password of the request of Post.